# Static python method to XML escape string which supports quotes

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have a string that have both XML escaped characters and non-escaped, and I need it to be 100% XML valid, example:

```
>>> s = '< &lt;'
```

I want this to be:

```
>>> s = '&lt; &lt;'
```

I have tried numerous methods with, lxml, cgi etc.. but they all expect the input string to not have any valid XML characters already:

```
>>> import cgi
>>> cgi.escape("< &lt;")
'&lt; &amp;lt;'
```

or

```
>>> from xml.sax.saxutils import escape
>>> escape("< &lt;")
'&lt; &amp;lt;'
```

Isn't there a standard method for this already?

Someone has to have had the same problem :)

Comment: So how should `< &` be encoded then? You have a *mix* of escaped and unescape data, and detecting what is *already* escaped is tricky at best.

Comment: And no, there is no standard method for 'guess what needs to be escaped'. If you have such a mix, then your input is a mess, frankly.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Probably the best thing is to fully decode and fully encode again. That would be the closest thing to autoguessing.

Comment: @Marcin: I was just typing up the same approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your best bet is to unescape, then to re-escape:

```
>>> from xml.sax.saxutils import escape, unescape
>>> unescape("< &lt;")
'< <'
>>> escape(unescape("< &lt;"))
'&lt; &lt;'
```