# Strange characters when writing html file open(file.html, 'a', encodint=utf-8) python

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

I am using Jinja and BS4 to scrape html and paste into a new file everything works fine.

I modified it for another client and it threw me an encoding errror, I added the encoding `=utf-8` and it worked again.

However some of the text is now gobblydegook, in all honesty I don't know what it is but its not ASCII

> example characters: Ã¢Â€Â“  this is instead of a long dash.

With the other version of the script it works without having to encode and also throws out zero strange characters.

The full script is here: [git](https://github.com/johnashu/PRODUCTION/blob/master/Python/eBay%20API%20KIT%20-%20Maffas%20-%202017/EBAY-REVISE-LISTING/beautiful_soup_MASTER.py)

the offending item is line 133

## open the html

```
f = open(new_file + '.html', 'a', encoding='utf-8')

message = result

f.write(message)# write result

f.close()#close html
```

*Please note i have not pushed the new version with the encoding..

Im reading it from BeautifulSoup via a URL using requests..

```
r = requests.get(ebay_url)
html_bytes = r.content

html_string = html_bytes.decode('UTF-8')

soup = bs4(html_string, 'html.parser')
description_source = soup.find("div", {"class":"dv3"})
```

Comment: @Ludisposed Thanks for the Edit! :)

Comment: Are you **sure** that the file you read is encoded as UTF-8?

Comment: I'm gonna check that now! :)

Comment: If your code is also writing that file, then you must specify the encoding for the file write *and* the file read. Specifying it only for the file read will result to wrong results, like the issue you currently see.

Comment: eta: ill put it in the main comment

Comment: and what does `r.content` look like? Does it already appear to be broken?

Comment: eta.. wrong page! i did r.content on a test page!!

Comment: https://pastebin.com/DDMxYGaW

here is the paste...

Comment: The r.content appears to be `bytes`, you must decode them into `string` before you can use them. Example: `html_bytes = b'height range 4\xe2\x80\xb2 10\xe2\x80\xb3 to 6\xe2\x80\xb2 4\xe2\x80\xb3'` (this is part of the content, taken from that pastebin). Now you can do `html_string = html_bytes.decode('UTF-8')`. After that you have a string you can pass to BeautifulSoup.

Comment: http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/272691885320 lionk to the rendered html

Comment: i have edited my main comment with what i think you mean.. but its still the same,..

Comment: Give me the URL of the page you are reading.

Comment: src:   http://vi.vipr.ebaydesc.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItemDescV4&item=271796888350

dst: http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/272692049069   (in prodcution src and dst will be the same..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.text` (not `.content`!) to get the [decoded response content](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content) from the requests module. This way you don't have to manually decode the response. The requests module will automatically pick the proper encoding by looking at the HTTP response headers.

```
import codecs
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4

def get_ebay_item_html(item_id):
    ebay_url = 'http://vi.vipr.ebaydesc.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItemDescV4&item='
    r = requests.get(ebay_url + str(item_id))

    return r.text
```

Now we can retrieve an item:

```
item_to_revise = "271796888350"
item_html = get_ebay_item_html(item_to_revise)
```

...scrape data from it:

```
soup = bs4(item_html , 'html.parser')
dv3 = soup.find("div", {"class":"dv3"})
print dv3
```

...save it to a file:

```
with codecs.open("271796888350.html", "w", encoding="UTF-8") as f:
    f.write(item_html)
```

...load it from a file:

```
with codecs.open("271796888350.html", "r", encoding="UTF-8") as f:
    item_html = f.read()
```

...or send it to the [ebaysdk module](https://github.com/timotheus/ebaysdk-python/). For this I strongly dis-recommend using constructions like this one: `"<![CDATA["+ f.read() + "]]>"`. CDATA cannot reliably be built this way. Use a [proper XML encoding function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25247885/static-python-method-to-xml-escape-string-which-supports-quotes) instead, it's safer.

```
from xml.sax.saxutils import escape
from ebaysdk.trading import Connection as Trading

api = Trading(debug=args.debug, siteid=site_id, appid=app_id, token=token_id, config_file=None, certid=cert_id, devid=dev_id)

api.execute('ReviseFixedPriceItem', {
    "Item": {
        "Country": "GB",
        "Description": escape(item_html),
        "ItemID": item_to_revise
    }
})
```

In fact, the ebaysdk module appears to support an `escape_xml` flag, which transparently does exactly what the code above does. I think you should use that instead:

```
api = Trading(escape_xml=true, debug=args.debug, siteid=site_id, appid=app_id, token=token_id, config_file=None, certid=cert_id, devid=dev_id)

api.execute('ReviseFixedPriceItem', {
    "Item": {
        "Country": "GB",
        "Description": item_html,
        "ItemID": item_to_revise
    }
})
```

In my tests all characters looked fine at all points.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed response.. That all makes sense as my first attempt at this script was using XML but it was horrible compared to the beauty of BeautifulSoup.. if interested it is here.. [1]https://github.com/johnashu/PRODUCTION/blob/master/Python/eBay%20API%20KIT%20-%20Maffas%20-%202017/EBAY-REVISE-LISTING/MASTER_using_XML.py

I am going to brave the heat and crack on now.. hopefully you will get a ping with a happy face!

Comment: if you are interested in helping with my other problem in this script.. I would be most grateful!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44242571/loop-is-appending-when-it-should-not?noredirect=1#comment75494174_44242571

Comment: The code you link to in your comment uses regex to parse XML. **Don't do that, this is horrible.** I really hope this is only a attempt that you did not really end up using.

Comment: Ha i know , hence the BS effort instead.. 

I am getting this error with the functino..
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.vipr.ebay.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /itm/Error?item=&errid=19 (Caused by NewConnection
Error('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001FBCDCB5F60>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',))

but not without it...

Thanks for the escape code.. much better! i knew there must be something better than CDATA!

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but your question here was about character encoding problems and I already went above and beyond by reading your entire source code and re-tracing your steps to pin down where the error occurs. I think I have answered the question, I can't hold your hand with every error you get.

Comment: My solution outlines what you have to do *in principle*, with regard to not mangling the character encoding of a downloaded web page in the process. It does not provide a copy-and-paste replacement, it describes what you need to change in your code. Apart from that, all the code bits in my answer work, I have tested them (except for the ebaysdk bit, I'm not going to install that). The error very likely is in your code.

Comment: I thank you for your help. I did not expect a copy and paste solution. I thought we were in a discussion about the problem.  You don't have to help. You don't have to be involved and you don't have to get upset about it. I have progressed slightly with your help. I have changed all my CDATA to now use xml escape.

Comment: Well, we were not in a discussion about the problem (in other words - your definition of the problem differs a lot from my definition). For you, we are discussing all kinds of aspects of your code that prevent it from running. That's not how Stack Overflow works. We were discussing a specific character encoding issue, and *nothing else*. The character encoding issue arose from not properly handling the data you get, and I showed you how to handle the data more appropriately. Question->answer, no followup questions about unrelated things in the comments. Those are the rules. Very simple.

Comment: please accept my apologies.. I never intended this to happen! I have taken on board what you have said and im having a read of the 'rules' lol..

I hope you can forgive me as I really really appreciate your time, knowledge and help.. maybe im just a little over excited at having someone to discuss any code with!

Start afresh i hope :)

Comment: No need to apologize. I realize you are new and Stack Overflow works in an unusual way - it's simply not a forum. I'm not upset, I'm just drawing a line by laying out a core principle. Stack Overflow's usefulness comes from focus. The usefulness of long comment threads like this one is very low, nobody reads any of this. Making an interactive debugging session out of it benefits you, and exactly nobody else. That's why long comment threads are actively discouraged. If you have a reproducible problem (like that HTTP error), search for it or ask a separate question about it.

Comment: Thank you again.. It was the outgoing encoding that was the problem. Not the incoming data. Following your methodology helped me to that conclusion.

Answer (score -1):

```
f = open(new_file + '.html', 'a', encoding='utf-8')
x = f.read()

re.sub(ur'\\u2014','-',x)
re.sub(ur'\xc3\xa2\xc2\x80\xc2','-',x)
re.sub(ur'\xe3\xa2\xe2\x80\xe2','-',x)
print x
```

Comment: That fixes the symptom, not the problem.

Comment: Requires more explanation.